# Is every linear functional which is not constant zero injective?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Or does there exists a counterexample?

My thoughts are as follows:

Let $F:V\to\mathbb{K}$ be a linear functional, $F\neq 0$, where $V$ is a normed space over $\mathbb{K}$.

Assume there is a $x\in V, x\neq 0$ s.t. $F(x) = 0$. As $F\neq 0$ there are $x_1, x_2\in V$ s.t. $F(x_1), F(x_2)\neq 0$ and $x_1+x_2 = x$. (Is this correct?) Then $$0 = F(x) = F(x_1 + x_2) = F(x_1) + F(x_2) \neq 0.$$ So the statement is proven by contradiction.

Maybe it is a trivial question but at the moment I'm not sure if I'm overseeing something?

Comment: Note that $1+(-1)=0$, yet $-1$ and $1$ are both non-zero.

Comment: What is true is that any non-zero linear functional is *surjective*.

Answer (score 1):

If $\dim V\le 1$, then the claim is true (and your proof doesn't work). If $\dim V\ge 2$, then no functional is injective.

Comment: ah yes, obviously there are trivial counterexamples $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Arguably, all examples are counterexamples.

Comment: Yes of course, I just mean there are then of course super trivial ones. So my question is some how ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

The proof fails in the last step: $F(x_1)+F(x_2)$ is not necessarily non-zero, even though both terms are non-zero.